# Spark SQL : Is it possible to process row after row in an pre-defined order for a given data frame partition?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I am looking to partition my data frame(df) based on a column (SECURITY_ID) and then run df.foreachpartition(customfunction). This is working fine.

Inside each partition, based on a column (RANK) the data has to be ordered. This is working fine.

Now, based on the the order I want to process row after row in sequential order for each partition. For example -

Base dataframe :

```
+-------------+----------+----------+------
ACCOUNT_NO|SECURITY_ID| QUANTITY|    RANK|
+-------------+----------+----------+------
  32934789|      290X2|   -98763|       3|
  3S534789|      290X2|    45300|       2|
  3FA34789|      290X2|    12763|       1|
  00000019|      290X2|-10177400|       4|
  92115301|      35G71|     8003|       2|
  91615301|      35G71|    -2883|       1|
```

After partition and order by

```
+-------------+----------+----------+------
ACCOUNT_NO|SECURITY_ID| QUANTITY|    RANK|
+-------------+----------+----------+------
  3FA34789|      290X2|    12763|       1|  
  3S534789|      290X2|    45300|       2|
  32934789|      290X2|   -98763|       3|
  00000019|      290X2|-10177400|       4|



+-------------+----------+----------+------
ACCOUNT_NO|SECURITY_ID| QUANTITY|    RANK|
+-------------+----------+----------+------
  91615301|      35G71|    -2883|       1|
  92115301|      35G71|     8003|       2|
```

Let us consider this partition

```
+-------------+----------+----------+------
ACCOUNT_NO|SECURITY_ID| QUANTITY|    RANK|
+-------------+----------+----------+------
  3FA34789|      290X2|    12763|       1|  
  3S534789|      290X2|    45300|       2|
  32934789|      290X2|   -98763|       3|
  00000019|      290X2|-10177400|       4|
```

I need to process rows one after the other based on the rank in the increasing order.

This seems to be fine on single node machine. But I see that the processing is getting jumbled when running on a multi-node cluster.

How can I make sure that the order is guaranteed ?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with coalesce(1) followed by sort(cols:*) operation over the SECURITY_ID  partitioned Datafame to get new Datafame/Dataset sorted by the specified columns, all in ascending order.

```
df.coalesce(1).sort("RANK").foreach(row => process(row))
```

Comment: Thanks@hagarwal. This helped.

Comment: Hi @hagarwal, in that case, `df.coalesce(1)` will merge partitions into 1. So different partitions are not processed in parallel and will be less efficient. If my understanding is right, is there a better way to resolve that?